# vertical align a div next to another div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically align a div that has text that is next to a div that contains an image.

[image: photo of visual]

The content can have multiple lines in the title (if you see image).

Currently how the html is:

```
<div class="small-view">
    <div class="small-left">
       <img src="image.png" width="80">
    </div>
    <div class="small-right">
       <p class="post-title">This is a post</p>
       <span class="post-info>January 5, 2015</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to vertically align "small-right" to the image so it's centered based on the text within it. For some reason, everything I'm trying isn't working.

Comment: create a fiddle, it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all your blocks (`div`s & `p`) displaying inline, and apply the vertical-align to your image:

```
<div class="small-view">
    <div class="small-left" style="display:inline;">
       <img src="image.png" width="80" style="vertical-align:middle">
    </div>
    <div class="small-right" style="display:inline;">
       <p class="post-title" style="display:inline;">This is a post</p>
       <span class="post-info>January 5, 2015</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Corresponding codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbXwJe)

You can also use a single div:

```
<div class="small-view">
    <div class="small-left-and-right">
       <p class="post-title">
          <img src="image.png" width="80" style="vertical-align:middle">
          This is a post
       </p>
       <span class="post-info>January 5, 2015</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Corresponding codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvWjOL)

Comment: It did, sorta. The span now won't sit under how the picture I added in the original post is. So I'm trying to figure that out. @veve

Answer (score 2):

```css
.small-view div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px pink solid;
}
.small-right {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-view">
  <div class="small-left">
    <img src="image.png" style=" width: 80px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="small-right">
    <p class="post-title">This is a post <span class="post-info">January 5, 2015</span>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here you go: much bether now :)

What i did: i put the  in the

, change 80 > 80px changed some wrong **"**

Answer (score 0):

you can try with table. In one column the image and in other col text

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block level item, meaning that by default it will start a new line after closing the `</div>`. This can by overriden by the style `<div style='display:inline'>`, bet better is to use `<span>` which is an inline item

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS `float:left;` to     `.small-right`

Like this:    `.small-left {float:left;}`

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmyLz28j/

Comment: That doesn't vertically align the text.